# using scrapy with selenium together

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

i was trying to integrate selenium into my scrapy project
i had a middleware setup for selenium chrome as such
now it works fine  it loads the page and it collect data needed .

tho couldn't figure a way to implement more futures into the chrome instance running
such as scrolling to load more items for scraping .

### middlware

```
`class SeleniumMiddleWare(object):

    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        content = self.driver.page_source


        return HtmlResponse(request.url, encoding='utf-8', body=content, request=request)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        return response`
```

### settings

```
`DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    #'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
    'booksjs.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleWare': 491
}`
```

### spider

```
`class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        sleep(5)
        quote_item = QuoteItem()
        for quote in response.selector.css('div.quote'):
            quote_item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            quote_item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            quote_item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            yield quote_item`
```

i have tried adding function to the middleware such as scroll with no luck .
    `def scroll(self): self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")`

as when i try to call those functions from the spider i get .

TypeError: scroll() missing 1 required positional arguments: 'self'.

i aslo tried looking for a way to import same instance of chrome ( self.driver ) to the spider to control it from there ( meaning i tried to control same page lunch by the middleware from spider and give it command from there ) .

if you know a way to make any of those ideas work  or if there is some other solution to it .

I would appreciate the help .
thank you .

Comment: why reinvent the wheel when there are packages like `scrapy-selenium`?